# Compilation error due to same attribute type in multiple dependencies

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, dependencies, custom-attributes

In my code I have two dependencies (here `DEP_1` and `DEP_2`) that both define a `SerializableAttribute`. When I add `[Serializable]` to a class it complains that:

```
The type 'SerializableAttribute' exists in both 'DEP_1' and 'DEP_2'
```

Now I want to use the attribute from `DEP_2`, but even if I use `[DEP_2.path.SerializableAttribute]` and only have `using DEP_2;` it still complains about it.

Does anyone have a way around this, as I definitely need both dependencies in the project I'm trying to work with, or would I be best creating an entirely separate project and referencing it?

Comment: This is confusing (to me). SerializableAttribute is built into the framework. Are you redefining it? Can you show your actual code?

Comment: I'm not redefining it. One of the dependencies is the framework, but one of our dependencies does redefine it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use namespace aliases?  Or just fully-qualify the attribute name everywhere you use it: `System.SerializableAttribute`.

Comment: Nope, fully qualifying the name doesn't seem to be enough - it still complains at me.